# How to use mermaid chunks in quarto?

Tags: r, npm, rstudio, quarto, mermaid

I am trying to embed mermaid chunks in my Quarto html document, but I am unable to run the chunks. I keep getting the error `/bin/sh mermaid: command not found`. The screenshot attached shows the problem:

[image: Screenshot]

I am able to draw the flowcharts using DiagrammeR package, but I do not want to do that. I want to use mermaid chunks.

The versions of the software I am currently using:

1. RStudio: 2023.09.1+494 "Desert Sunflower"
2. R: 4.3.1 "Eye Holes"
3. Qaurto: 1.3.450
4. MacOS: 14.1.1 Sonoma (23B81)

I have tried using mermaid chunks on the RStudio thats on my Ubuntu server. I get the same error:
`/bin/sh: 1: mermaid: not found`

I have installed the mermaid-cli on my device, and added the `package.json` to my path on the terminal, as per ChatGPT's suggestion (I used the latest command for `npm install` given on the mermaid [GitHub](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid-cli) page).

It will be great if anyone could help me solve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly did you add to your path in the terminal? You don't typically put the package.json on the path, you put the folder where the mermain binary lives on the path. Can you run `mmdc` from the command line? Did you restart R after you made changes to your path?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your reply, I added the following to my path: `export PATH="/Users/user/node_modules/.bin/mmdc:$PATH"`. I can use mmdc from my terminal. Even after restarting, I have the same error: "/bin/sh: mermaid: command not found"

Answer (score 1):

**Beginner Alert: I am not a computer guy, so you might find non-technical/technically inaccurate usage of terms in my answer**

Little did I know, I was not supposed to download `mermaid-cli` separately for Mermaid to work.

I get the error: `/bin/sh: mermaid: command not found` no matter what I add to the terminal* path.

Simply render your quarto document, and the mermaid charts should be seen in the html output. It's sad that you cant execute mermaid chunks.

*As a Mac user, I was on the `zsh` terminal. RStudio uses `/bin/sh` shell. Hence running `echo $PATH` in your `zsh` terminal will not show you what is present in the path for `/bin/sh`. You should add the paths you want in the `/bin/sh`'s path to `~/.profile`. Adding them to `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I also just discovered Mermaid.
I didn't figure how to run chucks inside RStudio, and I didn't searched too much.

However, I am able to render documents to visualise it. So I chose to work/develop with the [Mermaid Live Editor](https://mermaid.live/) and to verify my document by rendering it from time to time.

Best of luck,

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Vincent. Try the DiagrammeR package for R. DiagrammeR uses an older version of Mermaid out of the box, which will not allow you to use flowcharts. Update that using the script mentioned [here](https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/475). Now your mermaid calls will be executable in Quarto documents.